# Delegating domain in .ru to he.net nameservers

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm trying to delegate my domain progopedia.ru to use he.net name servers.

I did the changes via the registrar's web site, and whois lists he.het nameserves since about 10 days ago.

Still, he.het shows me this error when I check delegation:

> ERROR: Delegation was not found. Please delegate to ns1, ns2, ns3, ns4 and ns5.he.net then retry. We found ns2.hc.ru, ns1.hc.ru during our search.

Am I missing something?

(I suspect the issue might be specific do .ru domains, because I've done the same for several .com domains without any issues).

Answer (score 2):

ns1 and ns2.hc.ru are still the authoritative DNS servers for this domain. The he.net ones are just secondary ones.

https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=dns%3aprogopedia.ru

This config issue has to be fixed on registrar's side.

Comment: The link says "All of the name servers are Authoritative".

Comment: not for me -- I just get ns1 and ns2.hc.ru checked in the auth column; they must disappear completely, however.

Answer (score 0):

Now I think what's going on is a "deadlock" that the registrar wants the DNS servers to reply first, and he.net servers would not reply until the zone is delegated. More details here: https://forums.he.net/index.php?topic=3369.0

This can be resolved via he.net support.

Comment: Which registrar did you use? nic.ru has an option to skip server testing; this is exactly to resolve a deadlock.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov I use nic.ru. Can you point to where the option is, I can't find it.